# How to create adobe air extensions for vb.net applications?

Tags: .net, air, adobe

I need to create an extension for my adobe air application that displays a windows form on clicking my button on the stage. I found a way to create extensions but all the examples that i found ask me to create the extension in visual c++.

Is there any way to create an extension from my vb.net application?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not done anything with it personally, you should be able to use the Extension Context, and the Native Process.

Create an ExtensionContext instance
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WSb464b1207c184b143961a5e412937b5d5c6-7ffe.html

Communicating with native processes in AIR
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b060d22f991220f00ad8a-8000.html

Comment: But i am looking to call functions of a dll created in vb.net from within my adobe air application